# Sqlldr + Oracle Client on Windows

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have installed Oracle Client 12c (admin mode). Also, I installed Sqlldr module using custom mode. Is there a link Im missing? Where do i mention the connection details (tnsnames.ora) of my oracle database which is remotely elsewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the tnsnames.ora file goes in `<ORACLE_HOME>/network/admin`.